# Document Read and insert with locking/transaction in nodejs with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In reservation system, only 5 different user can create bookings. If 100 user call booking api at same time than how to handle concurrency with locking. I am using nodejs with mongodb. I went through mongo concurrency [article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/) and transactions in mongodb, but cannot find any sample coding solution with locking.

I have achieved solution with Optimistic concurrency control (when there is low contention for the resource - This can be easily implemented using versionNumber or timeStamp field).

Thank you in advance for suggesting me solution with locking.

Now the algorithm is:

**Step 1**: Get userAllowedNumber from userSettings collection.

```js
//Query
db.getCollection('userSettings').find({})

//Response Data
{ "userAllowedNumber": 5 }
```

**Step 2**, Get current bookedCount from bookings collection.

```js
//Query
db.getCollection('bookings').count({ })

//Response Data
2
```

**Step 3**, if `bookedCount <= userAllowedNumber` then insert in bookings.

```js
//Query
db.getCollection('bookings').create({ user_id: "usr_1" })
```

Comment: No reply means Mongodb do not handle this situation...is it?

Comment: MongoDB supports multi-document ACID transactions since 4.0 which is the solution to the use case explained here. Check out Lauren's blog post here for NodeJS: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-implement-transactions. Or mine with Java that covers a similar use case: "Don't sell more than you have in stock": https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/java-and-mongodb-40-support-for-multidocument-acid-transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had indepth discussion about locking with transaction in mongodb community. In the conclusion, I learn and found the limitation of transaction. There is no lock we can use to handle concurrent request for this task.

You can see the full Mongodb community conversation at this link
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/implementing-locking-in-transaction-for-read-and-write/127845

Github demo code with Jmeter testing shows the limitation and not able to handle concurrent request for this task.
https://github.com/naisargparmar/concurrencyMongo

New suggestion are still welcome and appreciate

Answer (score 1):

For a simple example of [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-implement-transactions), first you need to have a client connect to a MongoDB.

```js
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
await client.connect();
```

Once you have the client, you can create a session from which you can make transactions:

```js
const session = await client.startSession();
const transactionResults = await session.withTransaction( async () => {
     await client.db().collection("example").insertOne(example);
}, transactionOptions);
```

With `transactionOptions` being:

```js
const transactionOptions = {
   readPreference: 'primary',
   readConcern: { level: 'majority' },
   writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
};
```

Find about the Read/Write concern in the MongoDb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/#read-concern-levels).
Depending on your usecase, you may also consider [`findAndModify`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) which lock the document on change.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you can also try using Redlock (https://redis.com/redis-best-practices/communication-patterns/redlock/) for distributed locking or using Mutex lock for instance locking.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32932707)